# Search GROUP_CONCAT using LIKE

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have an SQL query that uses GROUP_CONCAT to get all people attached to a certain order.  Is there a way I can search inside the GROUP_CONCAT field?

```
SELECT orders.orderID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(contacts.firstName, " ", contacts.lastName) AS attachedContacts
FROM (orders)
JOIN contacts ON orders.contactID=contacts.contactID
GROUP BY orders.orderID
ORDER BY orders.orderID DESC
```

I want to add something like `WHERE attachedContacts LIKE '%Eric%'`, to only list orders with 'Eric' attached, but still include all other contacts in the query.

The query returns data like:

```
orderID atachedContacts
01      Eric Siegel, John Smith
02      Jason Jackson, Bill O'Neil
03      Eric Siegel, Jason Jackson, Neil O'Ryan
```

I want the query to return rows 01 and 03 because 'Eric' is in the contact list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT orders.orderID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(contacts.firstName, " ", contacts.lastName) AS attachedContacts
FROM orders
JOIN contacts ON orders.contactID=contacts.contactID
GROUP BY orders.orderID DESC
HAVING attachedContacts LIKE '%Eric%'
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked!  I guess there's no cleaner way to do this?

Comment: 'cleaner' is debatable, but you could use a `HAVING` clause instead of a subquery I believe, or a separate extra `JOIN` on contacts with the `LIKE` in the `ON` clause, but I'd test which one is better / performs better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `HAVING`, and the query I posted is only part of the full one, there are 3 more `JOIN` statements in there.

Comment: I tried adding `LIKE' to the 'JOIN` statement's `ON` clause.  It returned the correct records but only showed one name in the `attachedContacts` field, not all of them.

Comment: I went back into this code, and using `HAVING` is better than using subqueries.